# Primefaces Carousel showing all content in one page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.1 and if I do this in a plain xhtml page, it actually works fine. However, my problem is that I need to adopt the corporate look and feel and I am not enough of a CSS guru to know where to start debugging the issue that results from the inherited styles that cause the carousel to render all content in a list on the first "page", clicking on the other tabs shows empty content. I am trying to have each tab contain an iframe so I though that might be the problem. So, I tried simply using a simple example, slightly modified from the primefaces showcase:

```
<p:carousel numVisible="1" headerText="Tabs" style="margin-bottom:0" >  
                <p:tab title="Content I">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="content 1" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Content II">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Content 2" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Content III">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:outputText value="Content 3" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>            
            </p:carousel>
```

However, the output still gets rendered like this...

[Carousel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEIBu.jpg)

How do I get it to use the proper style shown in the Primefaces showcase and/or debug the problematic inherited CSS from the corporate CSS templates? Is there a way to force the standard primefaces function local to my application that would override the inherited issues?

Comment: Start by creating a [mcve]... and stating version info...investigating the client-side developer console, investigating if some css is not applied (overridden) and more...

Comment: I clarified the situation with an edit to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify, but we still cannot answer. _"How do I get it to use the proper style shown in the Primefaces showcase"_ By making sure the corporate css does not override them.  _"or debug the problematic inherited CSS from the corporate CSS templates"_ by using a browser developer tool. _" Is there a way to force the standard primefaces function local to my application that would override the inherited issues?"_ You could, all plain css ordering etc. But better to **not** have the corporate css screw things up. Have the designers of that use better selectors (css specificity).

Comment: as @Kukeltje already stated, be sure to inspect your elements with the help of developer tools. Compare your page with the showcase to identify css classes that corrupt your rendering. We can't offer more help when you can not (are not allowed) to provide your css.